# Why was this bounty vote deleted?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bounties, deleted-accounts

Someone awarded a bounty to me on [this answer](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/2921/what-is-thardid-jimbos-story/2923#2923) and then deleted their account. Normally, I would still keep the bounty reputation, and it would be attributed to the Community user. However, in this case, I seem to have lost the bounty reputation.

This seems to be a bug, because while my answer shows the "+200" mark, the answer's revision history and timeline do not show any evidence of a bounty having been awarded. It seems as though the bounty vote was deleted somehow. Interestingly, the question's revision history and timeline both show a bounty owned by Community and awarded to me.

Comment: You don't. Bounties are always transferred to the Community user. You'd only lose it if the question also got deleted. Where do you see you lost a bounty due to a profile deletion?

Comment: @animuson https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/2921/what-is-thardid-jimbos-story/2923#2923

Comment: I don't know why this is getting no-repro vote(s), since it's obvious to anyone that takes the time to look at the situation that it *can* be reproduced right there by looking at it: everything is still in the anomalous state. It might be a heisenbug or otherwise difficult to debug, but it's not as though it's vanished from relevance.

Comment: It is not in [revisions](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/posts/2923/revisions) but [timeline](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/posts/2921/timeline) shows bounty ended. no more details

Comment: @iDebug can you explain the [tag:status-norepro] ?

Comment: is 3.5k lowish? I mean he was in the top 10

Answer (score 4):

As far as *why* it was deleted, I personally have no idea.

However, this is not a bug. When the user in question was deleted, all of their votes were transferred to the Community user. Except that a bunch of their votes were also invalidated about 10 seconds before the deletion was approved. So in reality, a ton of their votes were invalidated, including this bounty, and then all of those *already deleted* votes got transferred to Community as part of the deletion process.

Invalidating bounty votes specifically does not do anything to the question's bounty record - so you'll always see the original bounty information on the question itself unless someone bothered to go clean that up. It's pretty much never useful for us to go do that because the only real benefit is beautifying the question's history.

It's also by-design that bounties just completely disappear from the reputation history if they later get invalidated. It's an exceedingly rare event that we do not account for in the code in order to show when the reversal occurred.

Comment: So bounty votes can also be invalidated as part of the serial voting script?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog If it's run manually by staff, they always are. They are not when run by automated systems, which includes the user deletion invalidation.

Comment: So, what happened here is that seconds before the user was deleted, their votes towards the author of the question were manually invalidated (for some reason) by a staff member?

Comment: @Sonic Correct.