# Changes to bounty rules: removal of double rep-retention, blocking of owner deletion

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties, deleted-questions

Adam Lear has been digging into the circumstances behind [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306694/do-not-refund-bounty-on-question-deletion-if-reputation-would-be-kept-on-an-awar), and determined that the behavior described there is likely an oversight: it should not be possible for a bounty to remain both awarded *and* refunded when a question is deleted.

### Reputation removed from those who've awarded bounties on deleted questions where the award is retained by the answer's author

So we've patched that up: starting today, when a question is deleted and has had bounties awarded to answers, the bounty amount will be refunded to the person who offered the bounty *only* if it was not also [retained](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/06/reputation-and-historical-archives/) by the author of the answer to which it was awarded (reminder that [bounties don't migrate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124953/does-it-make-sense-that-migrated-questions-doubles-your-network-reputation) - they're always refunded to the offerer). This also applies retroactively to older deletions that were subject to the previous rules.

Once recalculated, this will affect the *current* reputation of around 4,000 users network-wide. If it affects you, I apologize for the disruption; please let me know if you observe a change not reflected in the bounties you've offered in the past.

### New restriction on authors' ability to delete their own questions

While digging into this, we stumbled upon a more insidious problem: folks offering bounties on their own questions, awarding them immediately upon getting an answer, and then immediately deleting their question. This was allowed in cases where the answer had not yet received any upvotes and no other answers had been posted, and fortunately has been extremely rare... However, it is such an overtly hostile behavior that we've taken steps to block it as well: starting today, authors may no longer delete their own questions if a bounty has been awarded to an answer by anyone (unless that answer was already deleted).

Comment: "such an overtly hostile behavior that we've taken steps to block it as well" - agreed, did you also take steps against those who did it, at least undeleting the questions so that the points are redacted again?

Comment: No, I'm waiting for this change to settle in so that they don't get immediately re-deleted @Shadow [2/14: this is done now]

Comment: Good to hear! Never been a victim in either of those exploits, but when I saw that bug report I was like "oh, oh goodness..." +1 on the patch!

Comment: **folks offering bounties on their own questions, awarding them immediately upon getting an answer, and then immediately deleting their question.** Why would they do this? Were the bounty points refunded?

Comment: See https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4626/ and what it hyperlinks to for an aspect of questioners deleting questions once answered.

Comment: Yes, @ShmuelBrin. Of course, folks do that regularly even *without* bounties - hence the fairly strict rules on self-deletion. The bounty aspect just adds another kick in the teeth.

Comment: Since you're already fiddling with the machinery, how about some close votes on bounty questions, eh? ;)

Comment: That's a lot more machinery

Comment: So, will post owners also not be able to delete if half the bounty was awarded automatically?

Comment: Correct, @ano. Or if someone else offers a bounty on their question and awards it. Or if they accept an answer and the system awards the full amount to that answer as a result. Any extant award blocks deletion.

Comment: @Shog9 So that means no more self-deletion. But can community users vote to delete such question?

Comment: Mind you, the precondition for half the bounty being automatically awarded (the answer must have a 2+ score) has prevented deletion by the asker even before this change. (cc @Ano)

Comment: @NVZ I think community deletion is unaffected.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin: It is my understanding that the bounty would be refunded (and not awarded to the answer's response) in this case. In short, it's a scam: place a shiny bounty to attract answers and delete to get a refund and rip-off the answerer as soon as you get the information you need.

Comment: Can we fix questions not being able to be closed when there's a current bounty? How is that even relevant? It just keeps bad questions open for longer.

Comment: I'm confused, can you answer who the reputation from an awarded bounty will stay with after deletion. The author of the answer or the person whom offered the bounty?

Comment: @curiousdannii no, this helps to close such questions faster if you know how to write a compelling mod flag message. :) _"Please close this blatantly off-topic <explain what makes it close worthy>. Using custom flag because bounty on this question doesn't let me cast a close vote."_ I did it a few times - works like a charm... and mod close spares me from having to wait for 4 more regular close votes

Comment: I trust (actually hope) that it never happened so far, but about that "*New restriction on authors' ability to delete their own questions*", and just to double-check the way such things are QA-tested: what if the author is a moderator?

Comment: I've had twice recently that when a question of a low rep account accumulated close votes they quickly set a bounty so the question couldn't be deleted via close votes. Usually a mod flag does the trick with those.

Comment: Can we have the bounty NOT being refunded when the mod closes a question that was clearly of low quality?

Comment: @gnat indeed works like a charm. Last time I did that with a similar message I only had to wait four weeks, and Bob's your uncle!

Comment: @gnat afaik, there has been cases where by the time the moderator got to the flag, the bounty already ended and they *decline* the flag because, well, there's nothing to do.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens None of these checks apply (or have ever applied, for self-deleted questions) to diamond moderators.

Comment: @AshleyMedway Depends! If the question qualifies for preserving the reputation people got from the votes on it and its answers (currently, that's basically if it's over 60 days old), then the bounty rep will say with the answer's author. Otherwise, the answer's author will lose it and it will be refunded to the person who offered the bounty. Does that help clarify the behaviour?

Comment: @Braiam I think much depends on the wording of flag message. I broke my nose through few hundreds declines at different SE sites before I learned to find words that get flags acted upon reliably

Comment: Is there any way to know how much/if our reputation was affected?

Comment: If you didn't notice your reputation dropping (or increasing, for ~20 people) then you probably weren't affected, @Jeremy.

Comment: Is this related to [some](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2963652/nicael?tab=topactivity) [users](https://stackoverflow.com/users/875317/b-clay-shannon?tab=topactivity) (some before 2015) giving away almost all of their reputation points as bounties (protecting reputation points from vote fraud from being reversed? Compromised accounts? Altruism?). Or is that a separate issue?

Comment: It's only about plugging some edge-cases with bounties, @Peter. And to be fair, there are still plenty of edge-cases, including some with the functionality that *we JUST changed* - but now there are a few dozen mostly-benign edge-cases instead of a few hundred mostly-benign edge-cases + a few dozen abusive edge-cases. The only reason I'm featuring this is to avoid having to answer a bunch of questions about rep loss and deletion on down the road.

Comment: @AdamLear yes thank you :)

Comment: How will this affect the question in question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301852/why-was-this-bounty-vote-deleted)? Will the author be able to delete their own question if the bounty vote was deleted on an answer? (assuming the author's account isn't deleted)

Answer (score 21):

Personly I think a question should not be able to be deleted by the author if the author has put a bounty on the question (regardless of the awarded state).

If I do the work to provide an answer, I should know that the bounty will still be on the question when I post the answer a short time later.

Comment: What if the question became obsolete in the meantime (because the author solved it by themselves)? Wouldn't you rather waste only half the time?

Comment: Questions with an *active* bounty cannot be deleted by the author, or even by trusted users. If a blatantly off-topic question gets a bounty, a moderator can clear it (resulting in a refund) and delete it.

Comment: @Raphael If the question was valid to begin with, the author solving it doesn't make it obsolete.  The question should still have value to anyone else having a similar problem.  The author deleting it, rather than sharing what they did to solve it, would be harmful behavior.

Comment: This thread is announcing changes to the handling of **expired** bounties. If you do the work to provide an answer but you miss the deadline and the bounty does not get awarded, and the author then deletes the question before you can post the answer, how is the situation different to any other question which gets deleted before you can post your answer?

Comment: Active bounties already prevent author deletion; expired bounties with no answers and no awards are kinda meaningless - in theory, you could keep re-asking the same question and applying the same bounty, but in practice I could only find one or two examples of this and the questions ended up improving. My guess is there's generally too much visibility (and too many restrictions on bounty timing) to make this a productive strategy.

Comment: @Raphael If someone decided to award a bounty on something, I would argue it's not obsolete. Solving problems never goes out of style.