# Are bounties given by deleted users maintained or deleted?

Tags: support, reputation, bounties, deleted-accounts

Indeed, there is a difference in the answers of the two moderators Grace Note and Nick Craver.

I quote Grace Note in her comment on an answer to [Bounties from deleted accounts should still be awarded; at least, the indicator should be removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85954/bounties-from-deleted-accounts-should-still-be-awarded-al-least-the-indicator/89614#comment211447_86028):

> I'm here to explain to you why the current system removes bounties
>   from deleted users, which is tied to this design of reputation as a
>   measure of the visible present.

But Nick Craver says, and [I quote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89614/446930):

> Going forward bounties from deleted accounts will be moved to (owned)
>   by Community and will be awarded at the end of the period as they
>   normally would (e.g. when the bounty starter doesn't award and 7 days
>   is up).

I asked Nick Craver about it, but he didn't answer. Is it possible for SE staff to give a clear and unambiguous answer?

Comment: It sounds like Nick is talking about bounties that are active when the account is deleted, though the answer is on a question about historical bounties.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Thank you for your comment. Indeed, it is a possibility that once the bounties are awarded by the community, they would be deleted as Grace Note said?
But your answer also makes me understand that the moderators do not have access to this knowledge, that it is not official and that there is doubt in this case.

Comment: Some moderator might know how it works; it's just that *I* don't, so I hope someone who knows (employee or otherwise) answers your question.  If I could remember (or knew how to find) examples on the sites where I have a diamond, I could look at the history to maybe figure it out.  But off hand I don't know how to find bounties awarded by accounts that were later deleted.

Comment: The bounty is not revoked. There was [one case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301852/why-was-this-bounty-vote-deleted#comment981566_301852) where it was removed, but an employee said it was a bug. (cc @MonicaCellio)

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Both cases are on the site since the author of the question to which Grace Note and Nick Craver answered him lost his bonus. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85954/446930 Does this mean that their retention or deletion is assessed on a case-by-case basis by the ES team and that there is no general rule?

Answer (score 6):

They are maintained.

You can search for bounties by a now-deleted user via a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1098826/bounties-by-deleted-users). You'll need ♦ moderator tools to check the deletion date of a user, but [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/314362/revisions) is a bounty posted by a user who was deleted a few months after the bounty and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/55935/revisions) is one where the account was deleted while the bounty was still active. In the latter case, the deleted user can't award the full bounty, of course. In both cases, you can check that the answer itself "has been awarded bounties worth 50/100 reputation by Community" and the reputation gain is still visible in the answerers' profiles.

I think Grace Note's answer describes the situation before May 2011, and Nick's post announces a change in the system, which also explains why he [added the [status-completed] tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/85954/revisions).

Comment: Are there any other cases where the bounty vote was [accidentally deleted when the user was deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301852/why-was-this-bounty-vote-deleted#comment981566_301852)?

Comment: I doubt I can check that with SEDE. I'd need to visit each bountied post separately to check ...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But when a high-profile user deletes his account, the votes he has made are not deleted. While they are when a lambda user deletes his account. Are you sure that this is not the same principle: when the user has a very high reputation, its bonuses are retained and if not deleted?

Comment: Votes are not deleted in (relatively) rare cases where the user has made a lot of votes (not necessarily if they have a lot of reputation, though there is some correlation). I can't say with 100% certainty, but I doubt the votes of all of those 29 users I checked were retained.

Comment: @Andre Bounty votes are not included in the vote deletion when users are deleted. Even if all their other votes get deleted, bounties are always transferred to the Community user. If we see bounty abuse that should be reversed, we have to do that manually.

Comment: @animuson Thank you for your feedback. If it is an official answer from the SE Staff, can you officially answer this question on behalf of the SE Staff?

Comment: @AndréC I emailed SE and the reply was that `Dear , There is already an answer to that question confirmed by an employee. There is no need to reply any further to it.

Regards,
Stack Overflow Team`

Comment: @Raaja Did you tell them that there are several contradictory answers?

Comment: @AndréC yes indeed, I have cited the questions in the link. And, the above-mentioned reply is what I've got.

Comment: @Raaja Do you know why they don't just say what the official answer is?

Comment: @AndréC I think that was sufficiently answered in their reply which I have pasted before.

Comment: @Raaja The problem is that there is no official response since the only moderator who replied acknowledged that he did not know, so no moderator was officially informed. This is a deliberate desire of SE to never reply officially. They simply leave comments, but never respond officially

Comment: @AndréC I dont know about that. But I think they have sufficiently answered the question imo.

Comment: @Raaja The only moderator who officially replied acknowledged that he did not know.... The rest is conjecture.

Comment: @AndréC there is no conjecture. Its may be better if you directly contact SE and get clarified.

Comment: @Raaja You just did and they refused to be clear.

Comment: @AndréC "there is no official response" is not true, you got a conformation that the answer is correct by animuson, both an employ and mod, that is about as official as it can be. "he did not know" - based on the user name, I think you should apologise ... "several contradictory answers" there are no contradictory answers, just one answer which stated the current situation at the time of writing and another answer a month later that says that it was now changed.

Comment: @samcarter Nice to see you here :-). I asked animuson if this was an official answer. He didn't answer. So, it's not an answer, it's just a comment like Monica Cellio's, who admits she doesn't know.

Comment: @AndréC you should make it clear which part you dont understand and which part make you think it's just a comment. Moreover, why was the SE reply not sufficient? If you dont want to accept the SE reply, either you should write them (which you are not ready to do so) or ask a new question where you explain why you think this is a conspiracy by SE.

Comment: Also you should note that SE replied for that comment.

Comment: @Raaja Saying yes, this answer is the official answer is not very complicated to do. Instead, we leave a comment but refuse to say that it is official. On the other hand, I note that almost all the questions that are asked here are resolved by case analysis with the data analysis tool, as Glorfindel has done. SE prefers its system to be an object of study and analysis, rather than clearly stating the rules that their system applies. 

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

Comment: @AndréC I wish you best of luck with your pursuit.